# Why is the random variable I declared not changing even though I have created an object for it using randint function

Tags: python, random, import

```
import random
ran = random.randint(000,999)

n = int(input("Enter Any Number = "))

list=[]

for i in range(n):
    list.append(ran)
    print(i,"----",list)

print(list)
```

Comment: You should probably put the assignment of `ran` inside the loop. And please don't use `list` as a variable name in Python.

Comment: You call the function random.randint only one time, the variable ran will not change in your loop

Comment: ``random.randint(000,999)`` does not create a random object. It *picks* one number between 0 and 999.

Answer (score 1):

`randint()` returns a random value within that range. But calling that function only generates the random value once. So `ran` contains whatever that random value was from where you called the function; you never overwrite `ran` so it doesn't change.

Going forward I suggest using the back ticks to surround your code. Additionally, this is a question you should use google for, e.g. by searching 'random randint()' to see how the function works.

Edit: Looks like you formatted your code block now, so that's good. Another note is you should refrain from using Python keywords, such as `list`, for variable names. This overwrites the Python keyword which can be troublesome if you want to use various Python built-ins in the same file.

Comment: If I want to use a keyword like `list` as a variable name, I call it something like `myList` so it doesn't clash with the keyword.